# Reading inputs from CSV and using them for different functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv file with inputs, which come from users. The first column is the STATISTIC which are functions in my Python code, and the columns afterwards are different input variables for each of those statistics.

I.e. the WEIGHTED_MEAN statistic needs VARIABLE_COLUMN and WEIGHT_VARIABLE.

[image]

I read this csv file with the following python code where model_to_summarise is a df which I need to prepare a summary, and reprot_inputs is the csv above:

```py
def parse_report_input_table(model_to_summarise, report_inputs):

    statistics_dict = {
        "WEIGHTED_MEAN": Reporting.weighted_mean,
        "MEAN": Reporting.get_mean_of_columns,
        "SUM": Reporting.get_sum_of_columns,
        "MAX": Reporting.get_max_of_columns,
        "MIN": Reporting.get_min_of_columns,
        "COUNT": Reporting.get_count_of_columns,
        "PERIOD_END_BALANCES": Reporting.period_end_balances,
        "PERIOD_START_BALANCES": Reporting.period_start_balances,
        "AVERAGE_BALANCES": Reporting.average_balances,
        "RATIO_V1": Reporting.ratio_calculation_v1,
        "RATIO_V2": Reporting.ratio_calculation_v2
    }

    list_of_stat_reports = []
    group_by_variables = report_inputs["GROUP_BY_VARIABLES"][0].split(" || ")

    for index in report_inputs.index:
        function_to_call = statistics_dict[report_inputs.loc[index, "STATISTIC"]]
        if function_to_call == Reporting.weighted_mean:
            weighted_mean_report = function_to_call(model_to_summarise, group_by_variables,
                                                    report_inputs.loc[index, "VARIABLE_COLUMN"],
                                                    report_inputs.loc[index, "WEIGHT_VARIABLE"])
            list_of_stat_reports.append(weighted_mean_report)

        elif function_to_call in [
            Reporting.get_count_of_columns, Reporting.get_max_of_columns,
            Reporting.get_mean_of_columns, Reporting.get_min_of_columns,
            Reporting.get_sum_of_columns
                                    ]:
            columns_to_stat = report_inputs.loc[index, "COLUMNS_TO_STAT"].split(" || ")
            simple_stat_report = function_to_call(model_to_summarise,
                                                  group_by_variables,
                                                  columns_to_stat)
            list_of_stat_reports.append(simple_stat_report)

        elif function_to_call in [
            Reporting.period_end_balances,
            Reporting.period_start_balances,
            Reporting.average_balances
                                    ]:
            balances_df = function_to_call(model_to_summarise, group_by_variables,
                                                               report_inputs.loc[index, "UNMODIFIED_DATE_COLUMN"],
                                                               report_inputs.loc[index, "BALANCE_COLUMN"])
            list_of_stat_reports.append(balances_df)

        elif function_to_call == Reporting.ratio_calculation_v1:
            ratio_df_v1 = function_to_call(model_to_summarise, group_by_variables,
                                           report_inputs.loc[index, "NUMERATOR_VARIABLE"],
                                           report_inputs.loc[index, "DENOMINATOR_VARIABLE"],
                                           report_inputs.loc[index, "RATIO_NAME"])
            list_of_stat_reports.append(ratio_df_v1)

        elif function_to_call == Reporting.ratio_calculation_v2:
            ratio_df_v2 = function_to_call(model_to_summarise, group_by_variables,
                                           report_inputs.loc[index, "UNMODIFIED_DATE_COLUMN"],
                                           report_inputs.loc[index, "NUMERATOR_VARIABLE"],
                                           report_inputs.loc[index, "DENOMINATOR_VARIABLE"],
                                           report_inputs.loc[index, "RATIO_NAME"])
            list_of_stat_reports.append(ratio_df_v2)

        else:
            raise Exception("{missing_stat} is not available at the moment!"
                             .format(missing_stat=report_inputs.loc[index, "STATISTIC"]))

    return list_of_stat_reports, group_by_variables
```

The first return from this statement is a list of the dataframes that were created (from the user's requested statistics from the csv file).

In this case the list will be filled with a weighted_mean_df, mean_df, period_end_balances_df and ratio_v2_df.

As you can see, each function has different inputs(some have similar so I have grouped them in the if/else statements).

The dictionary - statistics_dict is not very big at the moment and writing if/elif for each function is OK.

But this statistics_dict will increasy to 30-40 and writing and if/elif for each statistic is not very good coding. **Is there a way to make this more generic/dynamic ?**

At the moment I have written an if/elif for different statistics because they have different inputs.

This is a big question and if you need more explanation, please let me know!

Comment: what about passing the whole df to each function and then let the function extract the data that it needs?

Comment: I have thought about that but neither my team or myself like it. Because it would mean that each function is executed slower. And we would prefer the functions to stay as simple as possible (just do the calculation).

Comment: How do you mean the function would be executed slower? passing the df to the function to extract relevant data and calculate will be no slower than extracting the relevant data and passing it to the function

Comment: I know this is A solution, but I am looking if there is a way to not modify the statistic functions. I.e. read the csv get/extract the inputs and pass them to the functions.

Comment: Also, my calculation functions are written in PySpark, and in pyspark I cannot be as picky as in pandas, like .loc to select a row or index and such. I do not want to have both pyspark and pandas in a function. that is 1-2 lines now.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with a class like this:

```py
Class ExampleClass:
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3, all variables listed like that...):
        self.var1 = var1
        etc.


    def func1(self):
        func1 needs var1 and var3 so I use them by doing self.var1 and self.var3

    def func2(self):
        func2 needs var1 and var2 so I use them by self.var1 and self.var2

    etc. for all the functions

Afterwards I modify the parse_report_input_table function like this:

def parse_report_input_table(model_to_summarise, report_inputs):
    """
    Parse the csv table with inputs from the user.
    """
    list_of_individual_stat_reports = []
    group_by_variables = report_inputs["GROUP_BY_VARIABLES"][0].split(" || ")
    for index in report_inputs.index:
        reporting = Reporting(model_to_summarise,
                              group_by_variables,
                              report_inputs.loc[index, "NUMERATOR_VARIABLE"],
                              report_inputs.loc[index, "DENOMINATOR_VARIABLE"],
                              report_inputs.loc[index, "RATIO_NAME"],
                              report_inputs.loc[index, "VARIABLE_COLUMN"],
                              report_inputs.loc[index, "WEIGHT_VARIABLE"],
                              report_inputs.loc[index, "COLUMNS_TO_STAT"],
                              report_inputs.loc[index, "UNMODIFIED_DATE_COLUMN"],
                              report_inputs.loc[index, "BALANCE_COLUMN"])
        statistics_dict = {
                              "WEIGHTED_MEAN": reporting.weighted_mean,
                              "MEAN": reporting.get_mean_of_columns,
                              "SUM": reporting.get_sum_of_columns,
                              "MAX": reporting.get_max_of_columns,
                              "MIN": reporting.get_min_of_columns,
                              "COUNT": reporting.get_count_of_columns,
                              "PERIOD_END_BALANCES": reporting.period_end_balances,
                              "PERIOD_START_BALANCES": reporting.period_start_balances,
                              "AVERAGE_BALANCES": reporting.average_balances,
                              "RATIO_V1": reporting.ratio_calculation_v1,
                              "RATIO_V2": reporting.ratio_calculation_v2
        }
        list_of_individual_stat_reports.append(statistics_dict[report_inputs.loc[index, "STATISTIC"]]())
    return list_of_individual_stat_reports, group_by_variables
```

This way, when I call the class, all of the arguments are created but the function that I am actually calling takes only the ones it needs.

Will accept improvements because I have not worked much with Python classes before :)